# My js file isn't being loaded for chrome users

Tags: javascript, php

I have a set of functions written in a `javascript.js` file and have it called in my `header.inc.php` file used for the headers on all of my pages. The headerfile has your basic html head information and the script search to the file in question.

```
<?php
@session_start();
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/header_styles.css" type="text/css"     media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/content.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js_functions.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

Here are the contents of the javascript file that are called to the webpages through the header.inc.php file.

```
function default_h1() {
    document.getElementById('showh1').innerHTML="<h1>Register to Play!</h1>";
}
function join_humans() {
    document.getElementById('showh1').innerHTML="<h1 id=\"bluefont\">Join the Humans!    </h1>";
}
function join_orcs() {
    document.getElementById('showh1').innerHTML="<h1 id=\"redfont\">Join the     Orcs!</h1>";
}
function human_factions() {
    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML="<option value='Faction 1'>Faction 1</option>";
}
function orc_factions() {
    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML="<option value='Faction 2'>Faction 2</option>";
}
function choose_faction() {
    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML="<option         value='empty_f'>*Choose</option>";
}
```

The javascript on the page in question that uses this file does not work in chrome. It works just fine in IE and Firefox and i can't figure out why it doesn't work in chrome.

***UPDATE***
Chrome seems to be loading the javascript file just fine. I actually went in and took the functions from the file and pasted them to the actual page and they just don't do anything at all. The functions won't call in chrome i just don't get it. Are they just not written properly for chrome or something? What gives?

Comment: For one thing, you have a missing `>` in `value='empty_f'>*Choose</option";` in your `</option` so that "could" break it. Rewrite to `value='empty_f'>*Choose</option>";` and try it again.

Comment: could have just been deleted when i copied over the code. I'm sure it's actually there in my real code.

Comment: use firebug to debug the js. check if the file path of js is correct!

Comment: Try console.log at key points to see what's happening.

Comment: Don't ya just love the "comments" box? ;-) Ok, so edit your question then with the missing `>` so nobody else doesn't say the same thing.

Comment: I don't really know how to troubleshoot using chrome developer tools

Answer (score 0):

Open up Chrome developers tools and check if the browser is receiving the js file. Also check for any errors in the js through Chrome.

Comment: This is not the solution.. this is a comment and should be there in the comment section

Answer (score 0):

You missed `>`

```
function choose_faction() {
    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML="<option value='empty_f'>*Choose</option>";
}
```

Comment: Whoever upvoted this, obviously hasn't bothered reading the comments. This is NOT the issue. OP said it was a mistake.